# Format a text box to display user input on runtime in form of thousand separator number with decimals

Tags: c#

i am still new to c# , i am trying to build a simple calculator with c# windows form.
i did all the coding but i am stuck in formating my calculator screen(text box in this case) to display numbers with thousand separator comma and decimal point.

for example: if the user input 1000 i want it to display 1,000 of if the user input 1000.0123 i want it to display 1,000.0123 on the fly(just like the windows 10 calculator)

i really appreciate the any help , i have been searching all around the internet for some solution and came to nothing

Comment: Are you just looking for the `.ToString()` method with format specifiers?  For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring

Answer (score 0):

use string format, in the textbox where you show the numbers :

```
txtNumber.text = string.Format("{0:n}",12521452.646521); // 12,521,452.64
```

or :

```
txtNumber.text = string.Format("{0:#,0.#########}", 12521452.646521))   // 12,521,452.646521
```

see more :
[C# String Format Method](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-string-format-method)

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = 1024.10;
Console.WriteLine(input.ToString("N"));
```

**Output:**

> 1,024.10

Format as a numeric value with 2 decimal places. For 3 or 4 decimal places you can use ToString("N3") or N4. For No decimal places ToString("N0")